# How to efficiently find distinct values from each column in Spark

Tags: performance, scala, apache-spark

To find distinct values from each column of an `Array` I tried

```
RDD[Array[String]].map(_.map(Set(_))).reduce { 
(a, b) => (a.zip(b)).map { case (x, y) => x ++ y}}
```

which executes successfully. However, I'd like to know if there was a more efficient way of doing this than my sample code above. Thank you.

Comment: You can use aggregate to avoid having to first map over the RDD and turn it into Sets. Are the Arrays of fixed known size?

Comment: Thanku ...... but,this is same as my code ...

Answer (score 4):

Aggregate saves a step, might or might not be more efficient

```
val z = Array.fill(5)(Set[String]()) // or whatever the length is
val d= lists.aggregate(z)({(a, b) => (a.zip(b)).map { case (x, y) => x + y}}, 
                          {(a, b) => (a.zip(b)).map { case (x, y) => x ++ y}})
```

You could also try using mutable sets and modifying rather than producing a new one at each step (which is explicitly allowed by Spark):

```
val z = Array.fill(5)(scala.collection.mutable.Set[String]())
val d= lists.aggregate(z)({(a, b) => (a.zip(b)).foreach { case (x, y) => x+= y };a},
                          {(a, b) => (a.zip(b)).foreach { case (x, y) => x ++= y};a})
```

Comment: Any method to find distinct values simultaneously in columns ,so that we can reduce more time !

Comment: Not sure what you mean. This steps through all rows, looking at each column in the row. Did you try mutable sets? I've edited the answer to add that.

Comment: I think its better to go with the first sample code using aggregate .... because foreach is not a good method ...and it is not efficient

Comment: Both use aggregate. The second is potentially more efficient as it creates less objects. `foreach` is not inherently inefficient or not a "good method", it's just a tool for getting the job done.

Comment: @AkhilaV please accept the answer to close the question !

Comment: What is `lists` here? When I run this code I get `error: not found: value lists`

Comment: It's whatever Array you're trying to find the distinct values in

Comment: Hm. I thought that's what `z` was. So then what is `z`?

Comment: A "zero" element. Something for `aggregate` to start on. In this case, an empty set for each column.