# How to find distinct values for different groups on a dataframe in Pyspark and recode the dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a big dataframe, the dataframe contain groups of people which are flag in the variable called "groups".

What I need to do for this dataframe now, is to presented in a more meaningful way.

For example in the following group 148, this is the table below:

```
df.select('gender','postcode','age','groups','bought').filter(df.groups==148).show()   

+------+--------+---+----------+----------+
|gender|postcode|age|    groups|bought    |
+------+--------+---+----------+----------+
|     0|    2189| 25|       148|car       |
|     0|    2192| 34|       148|house     |
|     1|    2193| 37|       148|car       |
|     1|    2194| 38|       148|house     |
|     1|    2196| 54|       148|laptop    |
|     1|    2197| 27|       148|laptop    |
|     0|    2198| 44|       148|laptop    |
+------+--------+---+----------+----------+
```

Gender has 0,1, so all these people in this group, will be changed to "people"
if all 1, then female, if all 0 then male. the rule but not for this group.

Now postcodes, the lowest is 2189 and the highest is 2211, then each case will change to [2189 - 2198].

For age, the lowest is 18 and the highest is 62, so it will be [25-54]

for bought, I need to check which items have been bought, these are [car,house,laptop]

So, this group recoding will end up as:

```
+------+-------------+--------+----------+------------------+
|gender|     postcode|     age|    groups|        bought    |
+------+-------------+--------+----------+------------------+
|person|[2189 - 2198]| [25-54]|       148|[car,house,laptop]|
|person|[2189 - 2198]| [25-54]|       148|[car,house,laptop]|
|person|[2189 - 2198]| [25-54]|       148|[car,house,laptop]|
|person|[2189 - 2198]| [25-54]|       148|[car,house,laptop]|
|person|[2189 - 2198]| [25-54]|       148|[car,house,laptop]|
|person|[2189 - 2198]| [25-54]|       148|[car,house,laptop]|
|person|[2189 - 2198]| [25-54]|       148|[car,house,laptop]|
+------+-------------+--------+----------+------------------+
```

and that will be done for all groups in the dataframe.

Any ideas?
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623897/how-to-efficiently-find-distinct-values-from-each-column-in-spark) I found something similar but is in scala
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps!

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType

df = sc.parallelize([
    [0, 2189, 25, 148, 'car'],
    [0, 2192, 34, 148, 'house'],
    [1, 2193, 37, 148, 'car'],
    [1, 2194, 38, 148, 'house'],
    [1, 2196, 54, 148, 'laptop'],
    [1, 2197, 27, 148, 'laptop'],
    [0, 2198, 44, 148, 'laptop']
]).toDF(('gender', 'postcode', 'age', 'groups', 'bought'))
df.show()

df1 = df.groupBy("groups").agg(f.collect_set("bought")).withColumnRenamed("collect_set(bought)","bought")
df2 = df.groupBy("groups").agg(f.min("age"), f.max("age")). \
    withColumn("age", f.concat(f.col("min(age)"), f.lit("-"), f.col("max(age)"))).select("groups","age")
df3 = df.groupBy("groups").agg(f.min("postcode"), f.max("postcode")). \
    withColumn("postcode", f.concat(f.col("min(postcode)"), f.lit("-"), f.col("max(postcode)"))).select("groups","postcode")
def modify_values(l):
    if l == [0, 1]:
        return "person"
    else:
        if l == [0]:
            return "male"
        else:
            return "female"
modified_val = f.udf(modify_values, StringType())
df4 = df.groupBy("groups").agg(f.collect_set("gender")).withColumn("gender",modified_val("collect_set(gender)")).select("groups","gender")

merged_df = df1.join(df2, "groups").join(df3, "groups").join(df4, "groups")
merged_df.show()
```

Output is:

```
+------+--------------------+-----+---------+------+
|groups|              bought|  age| postcode|gender|
+------+--------------------+-----+---------+------+
|   148|[laptop, house, car]|25-54|2189-2198|person|
+------+--------------------+-----+---------+------+
```

*Don't forget to let us know if it solved your problem*

Comment: Hi, thanks! I can see it works but I commented out the df.show() and merged_df.show()  and it runs under 7sec (Duration: 0:00:06.314000)  then I run "merged_df.show()" on its own and it takes: Duration: 0:07:46.214000, nearly 8 mins to show me a dataframe, why?  Also I need the same number of rows, not only one. Why is so slow? Can I fix it?

Comment: To have the same number of rows simply run `df.join(merged_df.alias("mdf"),"groups","right").select("mdf.*").show()`. Regarding slowness - in case you have huge amount of data then join would obviously be slow. Try `.cache()` e.g. `df1.cache()`, `df2.cache()` etc before using these dataframes in `merge_df`. It might help.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try. But it's only the show() line that takes 8mins, is this because it's a lazy operation? it will merge only when you want to show the dataframe? and yes, this should work for a very large data set, maybe 1 millions rows with many groups.

Comment: Dataframe shares common characteristics with RDD like lazy evaluations and `show()` seems to be an action function (though `show()` is not in the list of actions listed [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions)). BTW- this solution will work with as many groups (and obviously rows!) as you want it to process.

Comment: What if I wanted to leave the variable "bought" as original?

Comment: I am not sure if I got your question but I think you are interested in `collect_list` instead of `collect_set`.

Comment: If didnt want to change the values that are in the bought column, just leave them as they are, only one value

Comment: I just created a dataframe with only "bought and prediction" and run this!final_df=df_bought.join(merged_df.alias("fdf"),"prediction","left")      Thank you for all your help!